# Explanation of ccw algorithm

Tags: c++, ccw

I'm having some trouble understanding the ccw (counterclockwise) algorithm:

```
int ccw (Point P0, Point P1, Point P2) {
    dx1 = P1.x - P0.x;
    dx2 = P2.x - P0.x;
    dy1 = P1.y - P0.y;
    dy2 = P1.y - P0.y;

    if (dy1 * dx2 > dy2 * dx1) return -1;
    if (dx1 * dy2 > dy1 * dx2) return 1;
    if ((dx1 * dx2 < 0) || (dy1 * dy2 < 0)) return 1;
    if ((dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1) < (dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2)) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

This code it used to see if two lines intersect:

```
bool intersect (Vector2D l1, Vector2D l2) {
    return (((ccw(l1.start, l1.end, l2.start) * ccw(l1.start, l1.end, l2.end)) <= 0)
    && ((ccw(l2.start, l2.end, l1.start) * ccw(l2.start, l2.end, l1.start)) <= 0))
}
```

I can understand the code inside the intersect function, but I don't really understand the code inside the ccw function.

Why it isn't used the cross product?

Comment: Use cross product of what? You cant `cross` 2d vectors. It's only defined in 3D and 7D spaces, AFAIK.

Comment: @Drop in 2D vector math, "cross product" is often used to refer to the perpendicular dot product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code inside `ccw` function is written in a rather ad-hoc way, but it does use what is sometimes very informally referred as 2D-version of *cross product*. For two vectors `(dx1, dy1)` and `(dx2, dy2)` that product is defined as a scalar value equal to

```
CP = dx1 * dy2 - dx2 * dy1;
```

(In the formally correct terminology, `CP` is actually the *signed magnitude* of the classic 3D cross product of vectors `(dx1, dy1, 0)` and `(dx2, dy2, 0)`.) Obvoisly, that value is simply a *scalar* (*dot*) product, in which one of the vectors was replaced by its perpendicular.

If the value of `CP` is positive, then the shortest radial sweep from `(dx1, dy1)` to `(dx2, dy2)` goes counter-clockwise. Negative `CP` means clockwise sweep. Zero in `CP` indicates collinear vectors. (All this assumes that Y axis is directed up and X axis is directed to the right.)

Obviously, `CP > 0` condition is equivalent to `dx1 * dy2 > dx2 * dy1` condition and `CP < 0` is equivalent to `dx1 * dy2 < dx2 * dy1`. That's exactly what your `ccw` function checks by the very first two `if`s.

The remaining `if`s are dealing with the collinear situations.

If the vectors are pointing in opposite directions (which is detected by the third `if`), i.e. when `P0` lies between `P1` and `P2`, the function always returns `1`, indicating counter-clockwise ordering. Well, I guess that is just a convention assumed by the code author.

Finally, if two vectors point in the same direction, i.e. when `P0` lies outside the `P1-P2` segment, the decision is based in the vector lengths (the fourth `if`). If `P1` is closer than `P2` to `P0`, a clockwise ordering is reported. Otherwise, if `P2` is closer, a counter-clockwise ordering is reported. This is also just a convention assumed by the code author.

And, judging by the rest of the code, it is not about intersection of two *lines*. It is about intersection of two *segments*.

Comment: uhm. this might be due to language confusion (german speaker here), but isn't `dx1 * dy2 - dx2 * dy1` the determinant and the generalised cross produkt in R2 would be a linear function R2->R2: [x y] -> [-y x]???

Comment: @hop: I don't dispute the fact that referring to `dx1 * dy2 - dx2 * dy1` as a "cross product" is terminologically incorrect. But I do encounter it from time to time in informal conetxts. The value of `dx1 * dy2 - dx2 * dy1` is actually the *signed magnitude* of the classic (3D) cross product vector. This is probably that infomal usage stems from.

Comment: It's basically calculating the cross product in 3D assuming the vectors are in xy plane. It's explained in the wiki as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan